# pan when mousewheel pressed in Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt

I've got an application which handles zooming in/out using the mouse wheel with this event in Qt Creator.

**cpp**

```
void QNodeView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) {

    setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);

    // Scale the view / do the zoom
    double scaleFactor = 1.15;
    if(event->delta() > 0) {
        // Zoom in
        scale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor);
    } else {
        // Zooming out
        scale(1.0 / scaleFactor, 1.0 / scaleFactor);
    }
}
```

This is in the header file
**h**

```
protected:
    //Take over the interaction
    virtual void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event);
```

How can I add the ability to pan with the middle mouse button being pressed the user dragging the cursor?

I can post the project code if necessary just ask.
Thanks

Project files link (Qt Creator project)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbt4qqtdedltxek/QNodesEditor-master_01.zip?dl=0

Comment: Override mousePressEvent(), mouseMoveEvent(), and mouseReleaseEvent(), and inside each of those test for event->button()==Qt::MiddleButton

Answer (score 0):

At first, introduce some new member variables into your viewer class:

```
class QNodeView : public QGraphicsView
{
    // ...

private:
    int  m_originalX = 0;
    int  m_originalY = 0;
    bool m_moving = false;
};
```

Then reimplement `mousePressEvent()`, `mouseMoveEvent()`, and `mouseReleaseEvent()`.

```
void QNodeView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        // store original position
        m_originalX = event->x();
        m_originalY = event->y();

        // set the "moving" state
        m_moving = true;
    }
}

void QNodeView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (m_moving)
    {
        // panning operates in the scene coordinates using x,y
        QPointF oldp = mapToScene(m_originalX, m_originalY);
        QPointF newp = mapToScene(event->pos());
        QPointF translation = newp - oldp;

        translate(translation.x(), translation.y());

        m_originalX = event->x();
        m_originalY = event->y();
    }
}

void QNodeView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        m_moving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried in my sample and it didn't appear to move the view at all? should i post code

Comment: I've added the link to the dropbox files in the OP, I really appreciate your help on this. The project is from a public github repository.

Comment: did you get to check it out ?